# Updating problems Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, ppa

Whenever I try to update my computer by opening the Update Manager I get this problem and it just closes. Can someone help me?

```
W:GPG error: http:/packages.medibuntu.org quantal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EBC26B60C5A2783, 

W:Failed to fetch http:/ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/gsharkdown/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/gsharkdown/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: There is no longer a `quantal` directory on that server. If you are on 12.10 you might want to switch to the `precise` PPA.

Answer (score 0):

Open your **Software Updates** windows:

[image]

Go to **Other Software** and remove/disable the PPAs related to **http:/ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/gsharkdown/**

Close the Software Updates and repeat your update process.

The error is simply mentioning that the URL does not exist or the GPG Key could not be verified. So you need to remove that from the PPA list.

If the GUI app gives you any problems, then go to the sources via terminal:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Then remove the ones related to the problematic one. For example if I had a problem with the subdownloader PPA I would delete the following files in the `sources.list.d` folder:

```
subdownloader-developers-ppa-quantal.list
subdownloader-developers-ppa-quantal.list.distUpgrade
subdownloader-developers-ppa-quantal.list.save
```

A quick

```
sudo rm -fr subdownloader*
```

inside the `source.list.d` folder should do it.

And proceed to check `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see if it does not contain any PPA line related to subdownloader. In your case you need to look for some file related to the `ferramroberto/gsharkdown` PPA. Delete them and look for any line in `sources.list` related to it. Then do a `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: But I can't even open my Update center! whenever I try to open it, that problem comes up

Comment: @Richard did an update. Please test.